Looking for Options Which Pay Exactly When A Random Barrier is Reached
Supper that I fix two barriers $a<b$ and I consider a price process $X_.$ starting in the interval $(a,b)$.  Let V be a payoff function and let $\tau:= \inf \{t>0: X_t\not\in (a,b)\}$.
Are there options which pay $V(X_{\tau})$? That is they pay some function V of the underlying but only at the moment when the price reaches either the lower or upper barriers?
All the barrier options Ive seen only start to pay when a barrier is reached, but they do not activate at that exact time.

Specificically, I want to compute the following (where $\mathbb{Q}$ is an ELMM for the discounted price process $X_{\cdot}$)
$$
v(x):=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}\big[V(X_{\tau})|X_0=x\big]
$$
but I'm wondering if such options are really traded?

You mean the options mature and pay the function $V(X_\tau)$ when the underlying hits the barrier level?

Ya exactly.  This is different than the running max min I'm familiar with.

American digital, if you mean that the barrier makes it certain what you get at that moment. Otherwise, any Knock In is activated once you reach the barrier. Or what else do you mean with activate?

To my understanding, we are talking about a double Barrier Option with a rebate term that pays the underlying value (or a deterministic function of it) at the moment one of the two barriers is touched for the first time.

@AKdemy Ya but the issue is I cannot exercise before..

What do you mean with exercise before? You wrote you want to only pay at the moment the price reaches. That means you cannot exercise. That's exactly what an American digital, one Touch pay at hit etc do.

@AKdemy Are these types of options often traded, or just some "mathematical object"?

They are quite common and vendors like Bloomberg have templates for them.

Even if there is not fixed maturity time; that is, if the option only expires when a given barrier is reached (so its kinda perpetual)?

Perpetual options aren't very common. OTC markets structure pretty much everything though. However, the less liquid something trades and the more awkward the payoff is, the higher the premium will be.

Hmm so just to be certain, I wrote the payoff function under an ELMM in the updated question for the option I'm thinking about...This is a so-called "on touch pay"?
